# Issue with invalid Header

Tags: magento-2.1, error, magento-community, header

We recently started working with Magento, and while we have found answer to a lot of issues we have had, this one is fairly tricky as I am not intimately familiar with the magento core. I am also not well versed in PHP.

Long story short:

We installed absolute them.

This was a green light after the cache was cleared.

We then made some changes to the theme as follows:

Switched the color of the background back, and forth.

Uploaded images

Configured UPS shipping

Configured a couple blocks

Reverted some configurations in an effort, 
(Of course clearing cache each time) And we are currently with the below StackTrace. Help is appreciated.

```
#1 /home/user/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(448): Zend\Http\Header\GenericHeader::fromString('X-Magento-Tags:...')
#2 /home/user/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(287): Zend\Http\Headers->lazyLoadHeader(9)
#3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(31): Zend\Http\Headers->get('X-Magento-Tags')
#4 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response->getHeader('X-Magento-Tags')
#5 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(83): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->getHeader('X-Magento-Tags')
#6 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#8 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#9 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 /home/user/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}[root@srv1 report]#
```

**EDIT**

Alright so I ran the following due to the update today

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.4 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

now I have the stack trace

```
#0 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php(54): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Function mcrypt...', '/home/user/...', 54, Array)
#1 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->__construct('9475d949bdedede...', 'rijndael-256', 'cbc', 'nVcS2cCxAdQxJxe...')
#2 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('9475d949bdedede...', 2, 'nVcS2cCxAdQxJxe...')
#3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(109): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('a4AUV+R670BBjY8...')
#4 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('0:2:nVcS2cCxAdQ...')
#5 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(88): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted\Interceptor->processValue('0:2:nVcS2cCxAdQ...')
#6 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(106): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->processScopeData(Array)
#7 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite.php(34): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->process(Array)
#8 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite->process(Array)
#9 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(102): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite\Proxy->process(Array)
#10 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#11 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#12 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#13 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#14 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#15 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#16 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#17 /home/user/public_html/pub/errors/report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#18 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(324): require('/home/user/...')
#19 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#20 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#21 /home/user/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#22 {main} [] []
[2017-02-08 17:50:53] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Function mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php on line 54 in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php(54): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Function mcrypt...', '/home/user/...', 54, Array)
#1 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(401): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Crypt->__construct('9475d949bdedede...', 'rijndael-256', 'cbc', 'nVcS2cCxAdQxJxe...')
#2 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('9475d949bdedede...', 2, 'nVcS2cCxAdQxJxe...')
#3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(109): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('a4AUV+R670BBjY8...')
#4 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('0:2:nVcS2cCxAdQ...')
#5 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(88): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted\Interceptor->processValue('0:2:nVcS2cCxAdQ...')
#6 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataConfigTypeProcessor.php(106): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->processScopeData(Array)
#7 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite.php(34): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataConfigTypeProcessor->process(Array)
#8 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Config/PostProcessorComposite/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite->process(Array)
#9 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(102): Magento\Framework\App\Config\PostProcessorComposite\Proxy->process(Array)
#10 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#11 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#12 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#13 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#14 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#15 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#16 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#17 /home/user/public_html/pub/errors/report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#18 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(324): require('/home/user/...')
#19 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#20 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#21 /home/user/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#22 {main} [] []
```

**UPDATE**

So end of day switched back to PHP 5.6 for MCrypt deprecation issue.

Back to original problem if anyone idea reply me.

Comment: Remove var folder and try to run static content command rebuild it.

Comment: @Nits So I moved my var/ folder to varBACK/ 
then ran
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Unfortunately still same error

Comment: If there is additional information that anyone would need, please do not hesitate to ask. It is a VPS and I have full root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A theme is an aggregation of many modules and these can amount to a substantial amount of complex codes to maintain.

--> taking a theme in your Magento system is like adding a software on top of something complex (that is Magento).. the sum is likely not trivial

--> your post dates back 1 year ago and Magento has evolved a lot since but your post highlights that theme is good value to purchase but can give big learning curve

My take on this is hopefully a solution for you: if really you want to make use of a theme, then make it an investment. By this, I mean study this set of modules and be ready for maintaining it going forward.

Now, with Magento 2 evolving much faster than in the past, it is possible that using a theme may consist in using some partners you have already who build themes so that you can reliably have support going forward

Answer (score 0):

SO if anyone has a real solution, I'd be interested. What I ended up doing was removing the absolute theme and restoring a backup I took BEFORE installing the theme (Like a good server admin). If you can't fix it, rollback.